# Java Regex Varied Groupings

Tags: java, regex

Examples of what I want to pass would be:

1. ".."
2. "blah"
3. "blah*"
4. "blah.blah"
5. "blah.blah*"
6. any of 2-5 (NOT 1) with [@attrib="value"] **or** [@attrib="value" and @attrib2="value2" and ...] appended to the end

examples of what I don't want to pass would be:

1. ""
2. "."
3. " "
4. "..."
5. ".blah"
6. "-blah"

basically want ".."

**or**

a string of a-z that could include but not start with dots or dashes
(optionally followed by a *)(optionally followed by a list of attributes/values)

with groups being:

1. ".." or a string a-z including but not starting with dots/dashes
2. "*" or StringUtils.EMPTY if no match
3. the group of attributes or StringUtils.EMPTY if no match

The regex I currently have is:

```
"^([a-z]+[a-z.\\-]*)([\\*]*)[\\[]*([^\\]]*)[\\]]*"
```

...which doesn't work if there is just ".." or if the first group starts with letters but ends with a dot or dash. Everything I've tried to do to make it work for these two cases has just messed up the entire thing.

All help is appreciated.

Via the regex in my comment below and changing the code that works with this regex a bit, I have it working for "..", however, I have not yet got it to work with the first group ending with a letter only. I tried adding [a-z]+$ to the end of that group:

```
"^(\\.\\.|^([a-z]+[a-z.\\-]*[a-z]+$)([\\*]*)[\\[]*([^\\]]*)[\\]]*)$"
```

...but that causes problems with the latter groups

Comment: Someone posted and then removed an answer that was:
^(\\.\\.|^([a-z]+[a-z.\\-]*)([\\*]*)[\\[]*([^\\]]*)[\\]]*)$

This *sort of* solves the ".." problem, although it creates an extra group, and if it is just "..", then that ".." will show up in only group(1) whereas the other originally first groupings (eg: "blah", "blah.blah") will show up in group(2).

Would prefer if I could keep the 3 groups and have ".." be in the same group as "blah".

Also, this doesn't solve if the first group is text that ends with a dot or dash.

Answer (score 0):

this regex seems to meet the requirements specified in your question:

```
^(?:(\.{2})|([a-z]+\.?[a-z]*\*?)\s?\[?(?:(@\w+="\w+")(?:\sand\s)?)*\]?)$
```

I'm assuming you're able to make start/end line assertions, since you're making them in your attempt. If not, remove the '^' and the '$' from the start and end, respectively.

In java, use this code to run:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?:(\\.{2})|([a-z]+\\.?[a-z]*\\*?)\\s?\\[?(?:(@\\w+=\"\\w+\")(?:\\sand\\s)?)*\\]?)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("target string");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        String targetGroup = matcher.group(i)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.